# How do I load a Unicode string into a TTreeView via a TMemoryStream?

Tags: string, delphi, treeview, memorystream

I need to do something with a Unicode string of a tree of a TTreeView, so I want to load this string into a memory stream and then load the memory stream into the tree view. How can I do this?

Comment: Question is not clear, you wont to add string as one TreeNode or what ? btw. what Delphi version you are using ? That is important because string is unicode

Comment: You really have to clarifiy. What do you mean with "do something with String of a tree of TTreeView"?

Comment: Guys, I have Delphi 2010. I create a tree of TreeView, add some other strings and save it in unicode as a file. Then I want to load this file of tree into TreeView but before I edit the file: delete added strings before. Then I need to save edited string into MemoryStream and load this MemoryStream into TreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You be tempted to use directly the `TStringStream` class intead of a `TMemoryStream`. But this `TStringStream` class will encode the UnicodeString into an AnsiString before storage, in the Unicode Delphi version...

So here are some functions to create a `TMemoryStream` instance with pure Unicode content, then retrieve back this text:

```
function StringToMemoryStream(const Text: string): TMemoryStream;
var Bytes: integer;
begin
  if Text='' then 
    result := nil else
  begin
    result := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Bytes := length(Text)*sizeof(Char);
    result.Size := Bytes;
    move(pointer(Text)^,result.Memory^,Bytes);
  end;
end;

function MemoryStreamToString(MS: TMemoryStream): string;
begin
  if MS=nil then
    result := '' else
    SetString(result,PChar(MS.Memory),MS.Size div sizeof(Char));
end;
```

Be sure that you `Free` the `TMemoryStream` when you won't need it any more.

By using `sizeof(Char)` and `PChar`, this code will also work with previous non-Unicode version of Delphi.

Comment: `procedure StringToMemoryStream(const Text : String; MemStream : TMemoryStream)` would be more idiomatic. Or even better: `procedure StringToMemoryStream(const Text : String; Stream : TStream)` and then use `TStream`s `Write` and `Read` method.

Comment: Smasher, it works String->MemoryStream and MemoryStream->String. But when i load MemoryStream into TreeView I get '!@#$%^&*' in it... Does not TreeView use unicode??? It saves file in UTF-8...

Comment: Yes, I do TreeView1.LoadFromStream(UpdateMemoryStream,tencoding.Unicode) and all warks

Comment: I never said that it wouldn't work. Since you accepted the answer, I guess your problem is solved then?

Comment: @Smasher I suspected from the question that one memory stream was created for each TreeView node. So it did make sense to me to put the instance creation in the function. Resizing an existing memory stream will be slower than creating a new instance, in all cases. So I guess my answer will be faster. And my purpose was to show how a TMemoryStream works. See for instance the SetString() function which is perfect for creating a string from a memory buffer: it will be faster than SetLength() + Read() because there will be no reallocation of the existing buffer.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: no offense, I respect your decision to put the object creation inside the function. I just thaught that these functions would make sense in a broader context.